# Core Data - How to check if an object relationship exists without firing a fault

Tags: objective-c, core-data, relationship, fault, nsvaluetransformer

There is an object A and an Object B. Object B has one attribute that is type transformable (image), and one relationship, which is to an object A. Object A *may* have a relationship to one, and only one, object B, or it may not.

As I enumerate through my object A array, I want to check if each object A has an object B. But, I don't want to fire the fault for object B (which would invoke the reverse imageToData NSValueTransformer). I just want to know if it is there or not. How can I do this without bringing object B into memory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can just test

```
if (objectA.relationshipToB != nil) ...
```

This will not fire a fault for the related `B` object because you don't access its *properties*.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I thought that objectA.relationshipToB would cause an automatic fault but I am glad to see that it does not.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift I got a

> Could not find an overload for '!=' that accepts the supplied arguments

error. My relationship was correctly marked as *optional* but in the generated `NSManagedObject` my `@NSManaged` property didn't have a `?` after it. So this check against `nil` failed. I added the `?` and then I could check for existence of the relationship.

**Before** (didn't work)

```
@NSManaged var myRelationShip: MyClass
```

**After** (worked)

```
@NSManaged var myRelationShip: MyClass? // <--- Added `?`
```